# Are there shaders or at least shader like things in Swing?

Tags: 2d, graphics, shaders, swing

Is there? Because I'm wondering if it supports GLSL, HLSL, or it's own shading language? I don't know much about Swing graphics. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 2):

No there isn't.

What you can do is use OpenGL in Java with [Java™ Binding for the OpenGL® (JOGL)](https://jogamp.org/jogl). JOGL can interoperate with Swing pretty well, so you can render 3D (or 2D) graphics with GLSL shaders in your Swing components.